# The last item in the state array is overwritten by the new object when addLog() is invoked. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import starterMessage from '../helpers/starterMessage';

export default (initialState = []) => {
const [ state, setState ] = useState([ starterMessage ] || initialState);

const addLog = (type, payload, user) => {
    let newLog = [ ...state ];
    newLog.push({ [type]: payload, user });
    setState(newLog);
};

return [ state, addLog ];
};
```

This hook is written for managing a chat bot's log.
This method is invoked at the ChatBox Component.

[Github Repository](https://github.com/zolomohan/chat-bot-ui)

Comment: What do you mean overwritten? Can you provide an example in your question?

Comment: This is the Initial State `[ { {text: 'hello', user: 'user'} } ]`. When the bot responds, the state must be  `[ { text: 'hello', user: 'user' } , { text: 'hey there', user: 'bot' } ]` but instead the state is `[ { {text: 'hey there', user: 'bot'} } ]` @JakeLuby

Comment: You might have a closure issue. Could you try to use the "functional update" form of `setState`? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: This works perfectly when a class based component is used. The problem only surfaces when i use a hook. @JakeLuby

Comment: @PierreV. It Worked. Didn't know i could get the previous value of the state like that. Thank You Very Much.